# What is the number of student that get less than 144 marks if the number of students taken the test is 2500?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

What is the number of student that get less than $144$ marks if the number of students taken the test is $2500$?
mean $=160, SD = 8$, mound-shaped distribution
I solved it like this:

First:

$z$-score $(144)= (144 - 160)/8 = -2$
$SD = -2   \to  95$%
$(100 - 95) / 2 = 2.5$%

Second:
Is it $2.5$%$ \cdot 2500 = 625$ or $6250$?

Thanks

Comment: $2.5 \% \times 2500 = 62.5$. Assuming normal distribution, there are approximately $63$ desired students.

Comment: Please review the [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and help

Comment: You're doing a rough approximation and with 2500 as the multiplier that may not be a good idea. In R:  `pnorm(144,160,8)` returns $0.02275013,$ not 0.025, and `2500*pnorm(144,160,8)`
returns $56.87533\approx 57.$